# Is it possible to leverage type safety with symbols?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-symbol

Looking at this [Typescript code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Alet%20s%3A%20symbol%20%3D%20Symbol('sym')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa%5Bs%5D%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0Aa%5Bs%5D%20%3D%20'f'%3B%0D%0Aa%5Bs%5D%20%3D%20new%20Date()%3B%0D%0A) :

```
class A {

} 

let a = new A();
let s: symbol = Symbol('sym');

a[s] = 2;
a[s] = 'f';
a[s] = new Date();

//no errors
```

We can see that same symboled property is referencing to a difference types .

**Question:**

Is it possible to use the symbol and yet , get  TS type safety ?

Comment: Is it specific to Symbol though? It's the same if it's `let s = 'foo';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn on `noImplicitAny`, you'll get errors on all three assignments because the symbol property is not declared and `A` does not have an index signature.  You can declare the property as follows:

```
const s: unique symbol = Symbol('sym');
class A {
  [s]: number;
}

let a = new A();

a[s] = 2;  // OK
a[s] = 'f';  // Error
a[s] = new Date();  // Error
```

(Note, it's a little bit of a lie to call `Symbol('sym')` a `unique symbol`.  Consider using `Symbol()` instead.  I remember seeing an issue discussing this but I can't find it now.)

Comment: I don't understand.  In `[s]: number`, you can put whatever type you want in place of `number`.

Comment: Yeah ...I've missed the `unique` part. ( will read about it).

Answer (score 0):

> TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or
>   'number'.

Seem like the key of your class has to be a string or number.

```
class A {
  [key: symbol]: any; // invalid
}
```

Do you look for something like this?

```
class A {
  [key: string]: number | string | Date;
  [key: number]: number | string | Date;
}

const a = new A();
const s: symbol = Symbol('sym');

a[s] = 2;
a[s] = 'f';
a[s] = new Date();
```